# Looking to compute $e^{\phi}\Delta^2 f e^{-\phi}$ in a coordinate-free way

Tags: vector-analysis

Let $f, \phi:\mathbb{R}^n\to\mathbb{R}$ with $\phi(x)$ looking like $\phi(x)=(x+a)^2$ for some $a\in\mathbb{R}^n$. I am interested in computing $$L_\phi(f)=e^{\phi}\Delta^2 \left(e^{-\phi}\,f\right)$$ in a coordinate-free way. What I mean by that is that the result should be entirely in terms of terms like $\nabla \phi,\nabla f, \Delta^2 f$ and the like, with no explicit reference to coordinates. Another way of saying this is that all derivatives must be explicitly acting on either $\phi$ or $f$ but not some combination thereof. It should also be fully simplified, in other words, it cannot contain terms like $\Delta (e^{-\phi})$. For example,  you can write
$$e^{\phi}\Delta \left(e^{-\phi}\,f\right)=\Delta f+(|\nabla\phi|^2-\Delta\phi)f-2\nabla \phi \cdot \nabla f.$$
The right-hand side is the type of expression I am looking for. As you can probably see, the calculations get quite messy in the case of $\Delta^2$, which is why I am hoping someone here can help me compute this with Mathematica.

Eventually, I would like to split $L(f)$ into a symmetric and an anti-symmetric (under $\phi\to -\phi$) part, $$L_\phi(f)=S_\phi(f)+A_\phi(f),$$ where $S_\phi(f)=\frac{1}{2}(L_\phi(f)+L_{-\phi}(f))$ and $A_\phi(f)=\frac{1}{2}(L_\phi(f)-L_{-\phi}(f))$, and compute the commutator $$[S,A](f)=S(A(f))-A(S(f)),$$
to give you an idea of what I want to be able to do with the result.

Comment: Please move the question back to the Mathematica SE. I am specifically looking to do this in Mathematica, so I can use the result, as I've written in my post, to perform even more computationally intensive calculations that would be unreasonable to do by hand. Hence why I need to do this in Mathematica.

Comment: I've flagged this for moderator attention to be moved back.  In the meantime, to keep it from getting closed down over there, I would suggest that you edit the question to make it clearer that this is a Mathematica question rather than a vector calculus question.  Perhaps make it explicit in the title, drop the careful mathematical definition at the top (unless it makes a difference to the answer), and mention that you're looking for ways to calculate using Mathematica nearer the top of the question.

Comment: (Also, my answer once it gets over there is probably going to be "Mathematica isn't great at doing things coordinate-free without an add-on like [xAct](http://xact.es), but it might be worth your while to learn how to use that.")

Comment: The question was migrated from Mathematica SE because a diamond moderator there felt it was off-topic.  If you believe that the question is on-topic there (and not here), please *edit* the question to highlight the relevance to that community. As the question appears to be on-topic here, and because it has already been *specifically* declared off-topic there, I am not going to reverse the migration.